# fread returns 0 even though the data inside is found

Tags: c

I need help in this chunk of code, I'm trying to update my file and my fread returns 0 even though the data im trying to update is found inside the file.

```
void updateFile(char filename[], int num, int update){
    int pos, checker, y;
    FILE *fp;


    if((fp = fopen("yes.txt", "r+")) != NULL){
        pos = 0;
        while(checker = fread(&y, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 0 && y != num){
            pos++;
        }
        if(checker != 0){
            fseek(fp, sizeof(int) * pos, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&update, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        }
        fclose(fp); 
    }
}
```

data inside the file is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Now im trying to find 5(num) inside the file and change it to another number(update). What I know is fread is supposed to return 1 after a successful read of data but in my case, after I found 5 using y != num, fread returns 0 to checker and I don't know why. I expect it was going to be 1 and not 0 and because of that, I can't update my file. Please help.

Comment: When you say "data inside the file is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}" you don't mean the **text** `"{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}"` do you?  You mean it contains binary, right?

Comment: How can you be sure you have found 5? What is the value of 'pos' after the while loop? Please, fill your code with temporary debug prints (for example, also `y` value after each iteration can help to understand what actually makes the execution exit the loop). Answer also @trojanfoe 's question, because if the file contains text you will have to do a lot of changes in your code.

Comment: I apologize for the terrible question guys. I am still new to this website and I'll do better next time. Also, thanks for the help , I found the fix now thanks to @Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely, what you have:

```
while(checker = fread(&y, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 0 && y != num){
```

should be:

```
while ((checker = fread(&y, sizeof(int), 1, fp)) != 0 && y != num){
```

As it stands, you're evaluating `fread(&y, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 0 && y != num` and assigning that boolean (0, 1) value to `checker`, and then testing whether it was 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on incoming data all I can do is guess at a few things. Also assuming the while loop runs to completion finding nothing. T

- [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problems. If the information in your file was not written by a C program writing an `int` the binary bytes in the file may be in a different order than you expect.
- Assuming you are reading a binary file with integer values, despite the .txt suffix, you should want to add a "b" option to your open. Else the very low values you are using can be treated as control characters, which can be filtered by libc.  In particular the \n and \r can be deleted or generated, depending on the OS you are running on.  "b" assures this does not happen. On Linux you should be safe as is.
- Assuming you are reading a true text file if you are passing in a binary value then things just will not work as true .txt values do not use 50 for '2' rather than \002.